# Need to overwrite theme CSS

Tags: css

I have been working on this problem for days now and I just can't seem to find the answer.

I am using Drupal 7 and I am trying to use E-junkie's shopping cart in one of my blocks on the frontpage. The pop-up overlay and etc. are fine but apparently my Drupal theme's CSS Styles is overwriting that of my shopping so it comes out wrong.

This is the website that I am working on: http://eastwestcards.com - Under the big View Cart button there is an Add to Cart button that you can use to add a free product for the sake of being able to see what I mean by the shopping cart coming out all wrong. My checkout button is all the way to the left and if you click an empty space at the bottom it actually sends you to checkout, the item lists and the rest of the tables have no borders or cell spacing/padding and a few other things.

Now this site on the other hand is how my shopping cart should like: http://pixilate.com/fonts/gardenia-px - Just click Add to Cart for the product and you will see the different between my cart and that sites'.

I have been looking for help all over and I've tried everything that has been suggested to me, I have tried exempting the cart's design from my CSS stylesheet, I have tried overwriting my drupal theme's CSS and etc, I've even tried using the View Source Chart plugin for firefox to try and determine which tags and etc. I should be trying to fix in order to change the appearance of the shopping cart on the site. I used the View Source Chart plugin because viewing my page's source normally doesn't show the HTML code for the shopping cart pop up because it is a javascript code that is provided by e-junkie that I simply put on my site. I am fairly new to all of this but I have really tried my best to fix this problem and I hope someone will be kind enough to help me! Thank you in advance!

---

I made this change "border-collapse: separate" and "border-spacing: 2px" and i also added this stuff at the end of my css stylesheet, some of it works, some of it doesn't but it seems to look okay now:

```
#EJEJC_window table {
    background-color: white;
        !important;
}

div#EJEJC_iframeContent td

#EJEJC_iframeContent div {
    border-width: 3px;
    border-spacing: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: green;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: white;
        !important;
}

#EJEJC_iframeContent th {
    border-width: 3px;
    border-spacing: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: green;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: white;
        !important;
}

#ejejctable table {
font-family: arial;
font-size: 12pt;
background-color: white;
border-style: solid;
border-color: white;
padding: 4 px;
!important;
}

#ejejctable th {
border-width: 4px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: white;
padding: 4px;
!important;
}

#ejejctable td {
border-width: 4px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: white;
padding: 4px;
!important;
}

#ejejctable tr {
border-width: 4px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: white;
padding: 4px;
!important;
}

#ejejctable tbody {
border-width: 4px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: white;
padding: 4px;
!important;
}



#tdHeader { padding: 25px; !important; }

td#tdPmntOptions tr { float:right; !imporant; }

#tdPmntOptions tr { float:right; !imporant; }

img#btnEJ { float:right; !imporant; }

#btnEJ { float:right; !imporant; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Igsis.png), you'll see what the problem is. The blue area is your link tag, and the checkout button is actually just an image that's rattling around in all that  empty space. Clicking the white area takes you to checkout because as far as the computer's concerned, you are, in fact, clicking the on the link tag (just not on the image that a human user would expect to click on).

The quick and easy solution is to just give that link tag "float:right". Apart from positioning elements, the float property also makes containers "shrink wrap" around their contents. In this case, your link tag will shrink down to the size of the button image.
You could also give the link tag a fixed width and height, but the float solution is more flexible.

Hope that helps!

EDIT: Just spotted that element.style.css is setting a tags to "display: block". There's your problem. Change that to "display: inline" and it should behave normally.

As for the line spacing on the table, style.css is setting border-collapse to collapse and setting border-spacing to 0. Changing those to "border-collapse: separate" and "border-spacing: 2px" should fix it.

Comment: What about the borders for the item lists and etc.. they are supposed to be like the one on the site.

Comment: Also for your suggestion i added this to the styles.css since i did not know which link tag i am supposed to refer to: img#btnEJ { float:right; !imporant; } - this removed the weird empty clickable area in the middle but the button is still on the left side.

#btnEJ { float:right; !imporant; }

Comment: The lines are hidden because on style.css line 488, you've set "border-collapse: collapse", and "border-spacing: 0". You want these to be "border-collapse: separate", and "border-spacing: 2px".

Comment: I just had a closer look at it and spotted where the problem is coming from. I'll edit the answer above to explain.

Comment: I made this change "border-collapse: separate" and "border-spacing: 2px"

Comment: I edited my main post and showed you the changes that i made, some following your instructions and some bloody random ones but everything looks good for now. I just have a few more concerns if you don't mind helping me with them, how do i center the image on top of the shopping cart, like which tag do i refer to and etc.? - The square button that you click if you wish to select to remove an item seems to be closer to be almost touch the top of the table's border, can that be centered and lastly to end my sorrows, how do i make the update & continue shopping buttons have a click effect?

Comment: By click effect i mean when you click the button it looks like it's actually being pressed down and etc. I was also wondering if the border-collapse changes i made might effect any other part of my site? Really thank you for all your help so far you really put my heart at ease this has been bugging me for so many days now.

Comment: I also forgot to say.. Where would i be able to find element.style.css? which problem was that fix supposed to solve?

Comment: sure, no problem :) the border-collapse separate thing will make all tables in your site have a 2px padding in between cells. are you using many other tables? Vertically centering the checkbox can be done by giving it "v-align: middle;", but be warned IE might ignore that. To style the banner, you can refer to it as "#tdHeader img", and what you need to do to center it is give it "margin: auto". so "#tdHeader img { margin: auto; }". Running out of characters, I'll do the click effects on another comment.

Comment: Click effects are done using the :hover and :active pseudo-class. for example, try adding "#btnUpdtCart:hover {color:red;}" and "#btnUpdtCart:active {color:blue;}". Tinker with that and I'm sure you'll figure it out :)

Comment: btw, "!important" has to be applied to each line individually. The way you've got it now, it's only applying to the last rule in each set, as that's the one that its tailing. Having said that, if things are working at the moment, that proves you don't need !important in all those places. Don't worry about element.style.css, by using !important, you've overridden it anyway.

Comment: What tag do I use to refer to the checkbox? - Should i just leave everything alone for now since it's working anyways? hahah.

Comment: I tried doing this to make the buttons hover and also to center the image but they didn't work, any idea? #tdHeader img { margin: auto; !important; }

#btnUpdtCart:active {color:blue; !important; }

#btnContShop:active {color:blue; !important; }

Comment: hmm, tricky... you can use "input[type='checkbox']", but that's a css3 selector and IE will probably ignore it. They don't seem to have any unique designators otherwise, so unless you did a blanket rule for all inputs inside tables in the shopping cart window ("#EJEJC_window table input"), Im not sure you can target them directly. Unfortunately, your update cart and checkout buttons are also inputs inside tables in the shopping cart window, so this might be more trouble than its worth. I'd use "input[type='checkbox']" anyway; At least users with good browsers will see it as you intended it!

Comment: Tried this as well for the buttons: #btnUpdtCart:hover {color:blue; !important; }

#btnUpdtCart:active {color:blue; !important; }

#btnContShop:hover {color:blue; !important; }

#btnContShop:active {color:blue; !important; }

Comment: Do i do input[type='checkbox'] { v-align: middle; !important; } in my css file?

Comment: Ah, the hover and centering arent working because whatever's generating your popup is inserting in-line styling right into the markup. Unfortunately in-line styling always overrides any other source of styles. The only way around it is to either edit the plugin (if you have access to it), or to use some javascript to alter the in-line styles after the page loads. Why not create a new banner image that is the same width as the popup?

Comment: "#EJEJC_window table input[type='checkbox'] { v-align: middle; !important; }" is slightly more narrowly targeted, but yeah your one works too.

Comment: Mine didn't work for the check box and also the banner gets reduced in size for some reason, it's actually bigger - the banner i mean.

Comment: Another thing - how do i change the font for when people edit the quantity of the product they want to buy? Sorry again so many question please don't get annoyed hahah.